# C# - swap Last,First MI fastest way

Tags: c#, string

Ok, I can certainly *do* this with some IndexOf, or even a Split(), but I thought I'd throw this out as a bit of a performance teaser.

I have data - like 100K's of these - in LastName,FirstName Mi and I need to make it FirstName Mi Lastname.

I think that SubString/IndexOf(',') can do the job, but was hoping for a more elegant/performant suggestion.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Hi LarryR, pretty sure my answer answers your question. If it does please make sure to hit the 'tick' next to it to mark it as accepted. If it does not then please let me know what it is missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.Split is probably the fastest/most concise. However .IndexOf is surprisingly the fastest in small tests for this case (where we can rely on two commas and use LastIndexOf).

Paste the code below into [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to test for yourself:

For 10,000,000 results (best indicator as early results could be highly variable) I get:

> Regex Time   00:00:54.1151103
>
> Split Time   00:00:21.6187375
>
> IndexOf Time   00:00:24.2403165

For 1,000,000 results I get:

> Regex Time   00:00:03.6016272
>
> Split Time   00:00:01.5575928
>
> IndexOf Time   00:00:00.9774164

For 100,000 results I get:

> Regex Time   00:00:00.2587501
>
> Split Time   00:00:00.1013721
>
> IndexOf Time   00:00:00.0980560

```
void Main()  
{  
    int count = 100000;  
    WithRegex(count);  
    WithSplit(count);  
    WithIndexOf(count);
}  

void WithRegex(int count)  
{  
    Regex _commaRegex = new Regex(@",", RegexOptions.Compiled);  
    string[] names = Enumerable.Range(1,count)
        .Select(i => "first,last,middle" + i).ToArray();  
    List<string> newNames = new List<string>(count);  

    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch(); 
    stopWatch.Start();  
    foreach (string name in names)  
    {  
        string[] split = _commaRegex.Split(name);  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
        sb.Append(split[0]).Append(split[2]).Append(split[1]);  
        newNames.Add(sb.ToString());  
    } 
    stopWatch.Stop(); 
    stopWatch.Elapsed.Dump("Regex Time");  
}  

void WithSplit(int count)  
{  
    string[] names = Enumerable.Range(1,count)
         .Select(i => "first,last,middle" + i).ToArray();  
    List<string> newNames = new List<string>(count);  

    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch(); 
    stopWatch.Start();  
    foreach (string name in names)  
    {  
        string[] split = name.Split(',');  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
        sb.Append(split[0]).Append(split[2]).Append(split[1]);  
        newNames.Add(sb.ToString());  
    }  
    stopWatch.Stop(); 
    stopWatch.Elapsed.Dump("Split Time");  
}  

void WithIndexOf(int count)  
{  
    string[] names = Enumerable.Range(1,count)
        .Select(i => "first,last,middle" + i).ToArray();  
    List<string> newNames = new List<string>(count);  

    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch(); 
    stopWatch.Start();  
    foreach (string name in names)  
    {
        /* This approach only works for 2 commas */
        int firstComma = name.IndexOf(',');
        int lastComma = name.LastIndexOf(',');

        string first = name.Substring(0, firstComma);
        string last = name.Substring(firstComma + 1, lastComma-(firstComma+1));
        string middle = name.Substring(lastComma + 1);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
        sb.Append(first).Append(middle).Append(last);  

        newNames.Add(sb.ToString());  
    } 
    stopWatch.Stop(); 
    stopWatch.Elapsed.Dump("IndexOf Time");  
}
```

Comment: +1 for providing the proof for my answer. :-) and for a generally much more complete answer.

Comment: For timing purposes, use `Stopwatch`, not `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually surprised at the speed of split. instead of using the StringBuilder, I am just going to create a new string= ar[1] + ar[0] (result of the split)

Answer (score 3):

However you do it, I/O is going to be the greatest time suck in this operation. It would have probably taken you longer to type the question than to actually run the program that makes the swap.

Comment: "It would have probably taken you longer to type the question than to actually run the program that makes the swap." -> Good assertion, my answer proves this :-)